# How to refer newly created subnets to another modules in terraforn azure

Tags: azure, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-azure

I am working on creating a platform on Azure using terraform and I have created a Vnet and 2 subnets by passing the variable to subnet creation using for_each. Now I have to reference these two subnets in my entire platform while crating different modules, like in aks cluster or application gateway. How can I pass this two subnets (may be I can change variable to three so it can be customized) to other modules and how can I refer them but identification which subnet I am using like with name is a good option.

My main.tf file

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = [var.vnet_address_space]

  tags = {
    environment   = "dev"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = {for subnet in var.subnets: subnet.prefix => subnet}
  name                  = each.value.name
  address_prefixes      = [each.value.prefix]
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name  
}
```

variables are defined below.

```
resource_group_name ="Dev"
location ="South Central US"
vnet_name ="vnet"
vnet_address_space ="10.16.0.0/12"

subnets = [{
        name ="DMZ"
        prefix ="10.16.0.0/16"
    },{
        name ="Internal"
        prefix ="10.17.0.0/16"
    }
]
```

Comment: Did you add outputs to your module?

Answer (score 1):

There are two conditions for you to use the subnets created before in other modules.

First, if you just use the code you provide in the root level with other modules, I assume you want to use the subnets in the aks module:

```
variable "vnet_name" {}

variable "resource_group_name" {}

variable "vnet_address_space" {}

variable "location" {}

variable "subnets" {}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = [var.vnet_address_space]

  tags = {
    environment   = "dev"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = {for subnet in var.subnets: subnet.prefix => subnet}
  name                  = each.value.name
  address_prefixes      = [each.value.prefix]
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name  
}

module "aks" {
  source = "./modules/aks"

  DMZ_subnet = azurerm_subnet.subnet["DMZ"]
  Internal_subnet = azurerm_subnet.subnet["Internal"]

  ...
}
```

Second, if you put the network code in a module and you want to use the subnets in other modules, then you need to define the output in the network module and use the output in other modules:

./modules/vnet/main.tf

```
variable "vnet_name" {}

variable "resource_group_name" {}

variable "vnet_address_space" {}

variable "location" {}

variable "subnets" {}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = [var.vnet_address_space]

  tags = {
    environment   = "dev"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = {for subnet in var.subnets: subnet.prefix => subnet}
  name                  = each.value.name
  address_prefixes      = [each.value.prefix]
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name  
}

output "subnets" {
  value = azurerm_subnets.subnet
}
```

main.tf

```
module "network" {
  source = "./modules/network"
  ...
}

module "aks" {
  source = "./modules/aks"

  DMZ_subnet = module.network.subnets["DMZ"]
  Internal_subnet = module.network.subnets["Internal"]

  ...
}
```

**Update:**

The above code uses the name of the subnet to quote the subnet, so you need to change the for_each in the `azurerm_subnet` into below and I also recommend this:

```
for_each = {for subnet in var.subnets: subnet.name => subnet}
```

With your origin code:

```
for_each = {for subnet in var.subnets: subnet.prefix=> subnet}
```

You need to use the subnet prefix to quote the subnet, like

```
DMZ_subnet = azurerm_subnet.subnet["10.16.0.0/16"]
```

the output of the subnet like this:

[image]

Comment: its give an error Internal_subnet is object with 2 attributes

Comment: @s_k_t I'm sorry, I made the mistake. See the updates.

Comment: @s_k_t Any updates? Do you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes I solved it. I used name in place of prefix for selecting it.

Comment: @s_k_t Well, if the answer works for you please accept it.